# How to convert double byte character/string to single byte and vice versa?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on the Japanese text and i have 2 requirement.

1. Convert all charters in a string into double byte characters. This string can contain single or double or both character but the resulting string should be double byte only.

**eg:** 東京都中央区晴海1丁目8番11号

**expected output:** 東京都中央区晴海<1>丁目<8>番<11>号. all <> should contain double byte characters

2. Convert all charters into single byte characters. String is similar to requirement 1 but resulting string should contain only single byte characters.

**eg:** ＡＤＯＲＥＳ，Ｉｎｃ．

**expected output:** ADORES, INC.

I am reading this data from a csv file which contain nearly 300 columns and only 3 columns need these operations and rest should remain same.

I've got below code from online but it throws error. `raw_comp_name` contain the data from csv.
`raw_comp_name.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('ascii')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Information

---

Japanese characters has a standards below. Double-Byte Characters are twice as wide as normal alphabetic characters.

- Double-Byte Character (Zenkaku, 全角)
- Single-Byte Character (Hankaku, 半角)
  [image]

You can get more details from [this link](http://www.gsis.kumamoto-u.ac.jp/opencourses_en/ipf/01/chap3-5.html).

### Answer

---

You can use this [jaconv | pip](https://pypi.org/project/jaconv/) module. It has a both Single-Byte to Double-Byte and Double-Byte to Single-Byte functions. See more details from module [documentation link](http://ikegami-yukino.github.io/jaconv/jaconv.html)

Attached example code below:

```
import jaconv

hankaku_text = '東京都中央区晴海1丁目8番11号'
converted_zenkaku = jaconv.hankaku2zenkaku(hankaku_text)
print(converted_zenkaku)

zenkaku_text = "ＡＤＯＲＥＳ，Ｉｎｃ．"
converted_hankaku = jaconv.zenkaku2hankaku(zenkaku_text)
print(converted_hankaku)

output:
東京都中央区晴海1丁目8番11号
ADORES, Inc.
```

Comment: As the full to half solution does not work for me and i found another solution in case anyone come across the same:    

`import unicodedata`    

`unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', 'ＡＤＯＲＥＳ，Ｉｎｃ．')`    

Output:
`ADORES,Inc.`